# Network weird ping issue

Tags: networking

I have two units connected to the same network, directly to a router (nothing in between).

The main PC (Called PC1) runs on Windows 10-OS and has the firewall off. I'm using a TP-Link external network adapter for wireless connection to the router. PC1 is assigned has a reserved IP on the router for its MAC, and im using DHCP for all other IPs.
The second laptop (Called PC2) runs on Windows 8.

Whenever i try to ping PC1 from PC2 (PC2-> PC1), i get destination host unreachable. However, if i ping PC2 from PC1 (PC1->PC2), i get request timeout for the first ping then it works perfectly. After that happens, i am able to ping successfully PC1 from PC2.

This is happening every time. In case i close the ping command on PC1, after 5 minutes of no communication between the PC's, the same issue happens again.

What i have tried:
-Disabled the firewalls and defenders
-Changed network adapter power settings to be always on
-Updated adapter drivers

Comment: I'm guessing here, but it seems the WIFI adaptor is going in to a sleep mode.

Comment: @davidgo i thought so that's why i disabled it (to stay on the whole time). Now i've brought i new adapter to isolate the issue